# Android Manifest Map error in react native

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-native

I get this error when click listing in android devices.. attach listing error and sentry report.

if need update AndroidManifest.xml .. i found so many AndroidManifest.xml in my source.

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/25501496/62419485-dcb8a380-b6b3-11e9-99bb-a0780134638d.jpeg

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/25501496/62432060-fdd6ce00-b75f-11e9-81de-11519a131125.jpeg

i tried add code in android manifest file..but i check got too many files

im using template from codecanyon " Listapp "

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [your API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key#get-the-api-key) in your AndroidManifest.xml file (which is usually located in app\src\main), within the `<application>` element, like the error message indicates.

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

in the meta-data tag, it must be:

```
<application>
   <!-- You will only need to add this meta-data tag, but make sure it's a child of application -->
   <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
     android:value="Your Google maps API Key Here"/>
</application>
```